# Цветовая схема для Midnight Commander

Tags: centos, shell

Добрый день.

```
CentOS 6.5
```

Пытаюсь изменить цветовую схему любимого редактора Midnight Commander, для этого в ~/.mc/ini прописал:

```
[Colors]
base_color=normal=green,default:directory=white,default:
marked=yellow,default:errors=red,default:marked=yellow,default:
executable=brightgreen,default:marked=yellow,default:
link=grey,default:marked=yellow,default:device=brightmagenta,default:
marked=yellow,default
xterm=
color_terminals=
```

Все хорошо, но в редакторе при просмотре файла остался синий фон: http://itmages.ru/image/view/2434625/f7da7158

Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно прописать, чтобы фон в редакторе стал прозрачным (черным)?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В самом первом значении в [Colors]

```
default: base_color=normal=green
```

В самом последнем.

```
default: editnormal=green,black, 
default: editbold=yellow,black,
default: editmarked=red,gray,   
default: editwhitespace=gray, black,
default: editlinestate=lightgray,white,
```

Подробнее в [мануале](https://www.midnight-commander.org/wiki/doc/common/skins)

Comment: Сделал, ничего не изменилось, когда просто просматриваю файл через F3 - все нормально (оно так и было), если открываю на редактирование F4 - то фон все так-же синий.

Comment: Остальные опции с перфиксом edit попробуйте.(см. обновление)

Comment: Нет, и после остальных все на том-же месте, только не пойму - почему вы в начале каждой строки default вставляете, а в конце каждой строки запятую?

Я когда делаю так-же - у меня вообще все слетает.

Comment: Там не должно быть никаких строк, вся секция одной строкой, если и это не помогает просто добавьте все параметры и смените blue на green

Comment: Взял из этой таблицы: http://itmages.ru/image/view/2434625/f7da7158 все параметры, где было blue, заменил на green, получил:
base_color=normal=lightgray,green:marked=yellow,green:directory=white,green:executable=brightgreen,green:link=lightgray,green:stalelink=brightred,green:device=brightmagenta,green:core=red,green:special=black,green:helpslink=yellow,green:viewunderline=brightred,green:editnormal=lightgray,green:editbold=yellow,green:editwhitespace=brightblue,green:helpbold=green,lightgray:dhotfocus=green,cyan:dhotnormal=green,lightgray


Все синим стало, как по-умолчанию ))

Comment: Все, разобрался, спасибо!